# From where to download hibernate3.jar?

Tags: hibernate

I started to learn hibernate and want to create sample application in Eclipse, in which to include hibernate jar file, but I cannot find it (hibernate3.jar) nor in `hibernate-release-4.3.5.Final.zip` (downloaded from http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) nor in `hibernate-search-4.5.1.Final-dist.zip` (downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/) archives.

From where should I get it?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.2.3.ga, you will also need to download the jars listed in depends on, anyway you could use a tool like maven to download it easier

Comment: Try to use Maven, which would download all libraries for you. Example http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example/

Comment: I have no idea what is maven. I am new to Java, Hibernate so that I know only Eclipse partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually jar is called `hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar`.
I used Maven to include it and all it dependencies in project, like were suggested upper.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.1.3/

I suggest you learn latest stable version and all the jars available at 
http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/

may be you have some other issue.

you may try this

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/hibernate3.htm

all the required jars are there

Answer (score 1):

agree with ALZ: in version 4, it seems be under /hibernate-release-4.x.x.Final/lib/required folder, and is renamed to: hibernate-core-4.x.x.Final.jar 
I included this jar and the compilation errors went away.